# Indicate a directory on Amazon's S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS services.
I've always used the code below to calculate NDVI for images that were located in a directory.

```
path = r'images'
dirContents = os.listdir(path)

for file in dirContents:
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        subDir = os.listdir(file)
        
        # Assuming only two files in each subdirectory, bands 4 and 8 here
        if "B04" in subDir[0]:
            band4 = rasterio.open(subDir[0])
            band8 = rasterio.open(subDir[1])
        else:
            band4 = rasterio.open(subDir[1])
            band8 = rasterio.open(subDir[0])

        red = band4.read(1).astype('float32')
        nir = band8.read(1).astype('float32')

        #compute the ndvi
        ndvi = (NIR.astype(float) - RED.astype(float)) / (NIR+RED)

        profile = red.meta
        profile.update(driver='GTiff')
        profile.update(dtype=rasterio.float32)

        with rasterio.open(outfile, 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(ndvi.astype(rasterio.float32))
```

Now all the necessary images are in an amazon S3 folder. How do I replace the lines below?

> ```
> path = r'images'
> dirContents = os.listdir(path)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 is not a filesystem. You will need to use different commands to:

- List the contents of a bucket/path
- Download the files to local storage
- Then access the files on local storage

You can use the [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) AWS SDK for Python to access objects stored in S3.

For example:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

# List objects
objects = s3_resource.Bucket('your-bucket').objects.filter(Prefix='images/')

# Loop through each object
for object in objects:
  s3_resource.Object(object.bucket_name, object.key).download_file('local_filename')
  # Do something with the file here
```

Comment: I think `filter` should have a lower case f in your example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to AWS, you may also consider [libcloud](https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library. This is a library that allows you to use different cloud solutions with a unified API. For storage solutions you could do (code from here):

```
from libcloud.storage.types import Provider
from libcloud.storage.providers import get_driver

client = driver(StoreProvider.S3)
s3 = client(aws_id, aws_secret)

container = s3.get_container(container_name='name')
objects = s3.list_container_objects(container, prefix='path')

# Download a file
s3.download_object(objects[0], '/path/to/download')
```

Some things to note:

- Files are stored in an S3 bucket (container). Although buckets have a flat hierarchy, you are allowed to use key names like 'path/subpath/file1' to organize files in folders.
- You need to authenticate access to the bucket. In the above code you do so by providing an id and a secret.